# Dynamically renaming Pandas DataFrame columns based on configurable mapping

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Python/Pandas here. I have 2 Excel files. In CSV form they look like:

##### mappings.xlsx (as a csv)

```
Id,Standard,FieldName
1,'Animal','Pet'
2,'Color','Clr'
3,'Food','Snack'
```

##### info.xslx (as a csv)

```
Pet,Clr,Snack
Dog,Blue,Pizza
Cat,Purple,French Fries
```

I want to read these 2 Excel files into Pandas DataFrames, and then use the `mappings` dataframe to *rename* the **columns** of the `info` dataframe:

```
mappings_data = pd.read_excel('mappings.xlsx', engine="openpyxl")
mappings_df = pd.DataFrame(mappings_data)

info_data = pd.read_excel('info.xlsx', engine="openpyxl")
info_df = pd.DataFrame(info_data)
```

At this point the `info_df` has the following columns:

```
info_df["Pet"]
info_df["Clr"]
info_df["Snack"]
```

But because we have the mappings:

- `Pet` ==> `Animal`
- `Clr` ==> `Color`
- `Snack` ==> `Food`

I want to end up with an `info_df` that looks like so:

```
info_df["Animal"]
info_df["Color"]
info_df["Food"]
```

But obviously, everything needs to be dynamic based on the `mappings.xlsx` file. Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to create a dictionary from `FieldName` and `Standard`:

```
d = dict(zip(mappings_df['FieldName'], mappings_df['Standard']))
info_df = info_df.rename(columns=d)
```

Note that [`read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) returns a `DataFrame`. The following can be simplified:

```
mappings_data = pd.read_excel('mappings.xlsx', engine="openpyxl")
mappings_df = pd.DataFrame(mappings_data)

info_data = pd.read_excel('info.xlsx', engine="openpyxl")
info_df = pd.DataFrame(info_data)
```

to just

```
mappings_df = pd.read_excel('mappings.xlsx', engine="openpyxl")

info_df = pd.read_excel('info.xlsx', engine="openpyxl")
```